# Selenium stand-alone-serer and PhantomJS

Tags: angularjs, selenium, phantomjs, gulp, protractor

For the moment, I have a basic angular app, generated by "generator-gulp-angular". In this project, I have 2 tests: 1 karma-test and 1 e2e-test (using protractor). The karma-test wil run without a problem, but with the other, I encounter some issues.

I'm trying to run selenium driver with phantomJS to execute the test, and in Chrome it works, in Firefox not (because of the upgrade), but trying to run the test on phantomJS wil fail. I have already downgraded my selenium stand-alone-server but now, selenium will give the error "driver info: driver.session: unknown". I'm using selenium 2.38 and phantom 1.9.x.

Can somebody tell me what to do? Should I adapt something in the conf-files of phantomJS node-module? Should I downgrade my phantomJS? ...

This is my protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
   //directConnect: true,
   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9292',
   rootElement: 'body',

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'phantomjs',
        'phantomjs.binary.path': 'C:/Users/--------/Documents/3de_Academiejaar/Stage/GitHub_Repos/proj_Jesper2/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs',
    },

  specs: [paths.e2e + '/**/*.js'],

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      onComplete: function () {
      },
      isVerbose: true,
      showColors: true,
      includeStackTrace: true,
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

Comment: FYI, e2e testing on `PhantomJS` [is not recommended by protractor core developers](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#setting-up-phantomjs).

Comment: I think I have no choice. It's a project for a company ...

Comment: Understood,  thanks. Though it actually can be argued. Just think about it: do you have real application users using PhantomJS?

Comment: "phantomJS wil fail" is not an adequate description of what goes wrong. See if you can provide more detail. What output do you see? What's the minimal code that produces this output?

Comment: I'm now referring to this question that I asked, I've dumped the selenium and I'm talking directly to phantomJS using the GhostDriver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407750/protractor-error-using-phantomjs