# Protractor error using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, protractor, ghostdriver

I'm using phantomJS and protractor to run an e2e-test on my angular page, generated by gulp (standard angular-generator). When I want to run the second command, I will get the following error: "error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability..."

- phantomjs --webdriver=5000
- gulp protractor

I already looked it up on the internet, also on stackoverflow, but it didn't come to a solution. Everyone says it's because protractor can't find the angular page and that I have to adjust the rootelement-option in the protractor.conf.js. I tried that, but that didn't work out for me... Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

This is my protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:5000',
rootElement: 'html',

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.binary.path': 'C:/Users/..../proj_Jesper2/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs',       
},

specs: [paths.e2e + '/**/*.js'],

framework: 'jasmine',
// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: function () {
    },
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
}
};
```

This is the index.html angular page:

```
<!doctype html><html ng-app="testJesper2"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>testJesper2</title><meta name="description" content=""><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor-79b86c72.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-56ebb463.css"></head><body><!--[if lt IE 10]>


<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
 <![endif]--><div ui-view=""></div><script>
      (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
      function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
      e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
      e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
      r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
      ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
    </script><script src="scripts/vendor-8ebd933c.js"></script><script src="scripts/app-a7333f52.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: I also get an other error: UnknownError: Missing Command Parameter - {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"25","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"localhost:5000"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"args\":[],\"script\":null}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},...

Comment: Could you solve this extra error? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. As I was working with gulp, I forgot to run a single command which screwed up the whole project... "gulp serve" was the key!